# Sending JSON Request to server?

Tags: iphone, json, post, nsmutableurlrequest

I have following JSON for sending request on server

```
{
    "name":"Home",
    "latitude":"45.5037078163837",
    "longitude":"-122.622699737549",
    "radius":"240"
}
```

and URL of for request is

```
  URL: https://api.geoloqi.com/1/place/create
```

I am making request like this,

```
    NSString *urlString= @"https://api.geoloqi.com/1/place/create ";
NSURL* url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlString];
NSString *jsonRequest = @"{\"name\":\"veer\",\"latitude\":\"45.5037078163837\",\"longitude\":\"-122.622699737549\,\"radius\":\"500\ }";

jsonRequest = [self JSONString:jsonRequest];

NSData* requestData = [jsonRequest dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString* requestDataLengthString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", [requestData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:requestData];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:requestDataLengthString forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setTimeoutInterval:30.0];
[url release];
[requestData release];
[requestDataLengthString release];

NSURLConnection *m_URLConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[request release];
```

What is wrong with this request ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JSON string seems to be missing 2 quotes after the longitude and radius values:

**Change**

`NSString *jsonRequest = @"{\"name\":\"veer\",\"latitude\":\"45.5037078163837\",\"longitude\":\"-122.622699737549\,\"radius\":\"500\ }";`

**To this**

`NSString *jsonRequest = @"{\"name\":\"veer\",\"latitude\":\"45.5037078163837\",\"longitude\":\"-122.622699737549\",\"radius\":\"500\" }";`

Comment: in DidRecieve, it is returning the same url, see this, what I am trying to do  https://developers.geoloqi.com/api/place/create

Comment: I am trying to create the request, given over their in the link,

Comment: to avoid such quotes error you can also create NSDictionary for sending json request. NSDictionary works as key value pair so did json

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your question what is your issue with that.

Anyway, are you doing also:

```
[m_URLConnection start];
```

after creating the connection?

Alternatively, you could create the connection using

`[– initWithRequest:delegate:startImmediately:][1]`

which allows you to specify that the loading of data shall start immediately.

Also consider using `[+sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:][2]` as a convenience constructor for your connection.

Comment: https://developers.geoloqi.com/api/place/create I want to do this, as written in this documentation

Comment: See this link, and I want to create request for this, but  I am unable to do it

Answer (score 0):

The Webservice URL you are trying to hit is seem to be using SSL. You may need to put access token in request header in order to get the proper response from web service.

Please see the link for authentication:
https://developers.geoloqi.com/api/authentication